# React.js: Click on answer option toggles the color of all options instead of just the clicked option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, use-state

Currently, on my quiz page, all answer options are colorized when clicked. However, only the single answer option should be recolored according to its correctness. The data is pulled from a data.json array.

```
export default function QuizCard({ title, scenario, question, answers }) {
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('gray')
  function handleAnswerClick(isCorrect) {
    if (isCorrect === true) {
      setBgColor('green')
    } else {
      setBgColor('red')
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Card bgColor={bgColor}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{scenario}</p>
        <h3>{question}</h3>
        <AnswerSection>
          {answers.map((answer => (
            <AnswerButton
              key={index}
              onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(answer.isCorrect)}
              isCorrect={answer.isCorrect}
              bgColor={bgColor}
            >
              {answer.answerText}
            </AnswerButton>
          ))}
        </AnswerSection>
      </Card>
```

What do I need to do to highlight only the selected answer in red or green depending on its correctness without recoloring all other options as well?

Thank you very much for your help and apologies for the vague question. I started coding 2 months ago and I am not yet so familiar with the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this that:

```js
export default function QuizCard({ title, scenario, question, answers }) {
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('gray')
  const [selectAnswer, setSelectAnswer] = useState(null)
  const handleAnswerClick = (isCorrect, answer) => {
    if (isCorrect === true) {
      setBgColor('green')
    } else {
      setBgColor('red')
    }
    setSelectAnswer(answer)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card bgColor={bgColor}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{scenario}</p>
        <h3>{question}</h3>
        <AnswerSection>
          {answers.map(answer => (
            <AnswerButton
              key={answer.answerText}
              onClick={() =>
                handleAnswerClick(answer.isCorrect, answer.answerText)
              }
              isCorrect={answer.isCorrect}
              bgColor={answer.answerText === selectAnswer ? bgColor : 'gray'} // assign bgColor in state only to the right answer and for others use gray as default
            >
              {answer.answerText}
            </AnswerButton>
          ))}
        </AnswerSection>
      </Card>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can shorter code in function handleAnswerClick that:

    `const handleAnswerClick = (isCorrect, answer) => {
      const color = isCorrect ? 'green' : 'red'
      setBgColor(color)
      setSelectAnswer(answer)
    }`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now :-)

Be sure that as soon as I reach the minimum reputation threshold, I will up vote your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting 'bgColor' for all the answer buttons. Instead you should set the bgColor only for the correct answer to color only it. A slight modification in the bgColor logic should do it.

```
export default function QuizCard({ title, scenario, question, answers }) {
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('gray')
  function handleAnswerClick(isCorrect) {
    if (isCorrect === true) {
      setBgColor('green')
    } else {
      setBgColor('red')
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Card bgColor={bgColor}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{scenario}</p>
        <h3>{question}</h3>
        <AnswerSection>
          {answers.map((answer => (
            <AnswerButton
              key={answer.answerText}
              onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(answer.isCorrect)}
              isCorrect={answer.isCorrect}
              bgColor={answer.isCorrect ? bgColor : 'gray'} // assign bgColor in state only to the right answer and for others use gray as default
            >
              {answer.answerText}
            </AnswerButton>
          ))}
        </AnswerSection>
      </Card>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!

Your suggestion has helped me that only one answer is now marked in color. Unfortunately, now only the first answer is marked red or green, even if I clicked on another option.

Do I have to pass the index at some point in my code?

Comment: Hey, yeah good point. You have to pass the key as well to AswerButton component as a prop, I edited the answer to pass answerText as the key.

Comment: Unfortunately, the adjusted index did not fix the error. Currently, only the answer with the entry "isCorrect: true" in the array is highlighted. The answer options with the entry "isCorrect: false" are not colored.

I think I need to create a state for my function that checks for me which answer was selected and conversely only recolors this answer according to its correctness. But unfortunately I don't know how to implement this.

Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You can shorter code in function handleAnswerClick that:

```
const handleAnswerClick = (isCorrect, answer) => {
  const color = isCorrect ? 'green' : 'red'
  setBgColor(color)
  setSelectAnswer(answer)
}
```